# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do paging and sorting in my Index view without using PagedList. However I am encountering the error -

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AQB_MON.Models.DeviceLog]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'AQB_MON.ViewModels.DeviceLogIndex'.

I have created my own ViewModel to pass parameters to the Create View. When I enter the DeviceLog Index View it is for a specific DeviceID and I want to pass this DeviceID to the Create View however I encountered some issues using PagedList. So I found an alternative however I encounter the above error.

My DeviceLogIndex ViewModel consists of -

```
public class DeviceLogIndex
{
    public DeviceLogIndex()
    {
        this.DeviceLogs = new List<DeviceLog>();
    }
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    public string mytest { get; set; }
    public List<DeviceLog> DeviceLogs { get; set; }
```

and my PageInfo ViewModel that is used for Paging and sorting is -

```
public class PagingInfo
{
    public string SortField { get; set; }
    public string SortDirection { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }
}
```

the first part of my view is -

```
@model AQB_MON.ViewModels.DeviceLogIndex

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@{
AQB_MON.ViewModels.PagingInfo info = ViewBag.PagingInfo;
}
```

I am thinking the 'info' declaration is causing the problem?

My controller is -

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var devicelogs = db.DeviceLogs
        .Include(d => d.Device)
        .Include(d => d.DeviceLogType)
        .Include(d => d.Device.ManufacturerModel)
        .Where(d => d.DeviceID == id);
    { 
        PagingInfo info = new PagingInfo();
            info.SortField = "DeviceLog";
            info.SortDirection = "ascending";
            info.PageSize = 15;
            info.PageCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)(db.DeviceLogs.Count()/info.PageSize)));
            info.PageCount +=1;
            info.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
            var query = devicelogs.OrderBy(c => c.DeviceLogID).Take(info.PageSize);
            ViewBag.PagingInfo = info;
            List<DeviceLog> model= query.ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PagingInfo info, int id)
{
    var devicelogs = db.DeviceLogs
        .Include(d => d.Device)
        .Include(d => d.DeviceLogType)
        .Include(d => d.Device.ManufacturerModel)
        .Where(d => d.DeviceID == id);
    {
        IQueryable<DeviceLog> query = null;
        switch(info.SortField)
        {
            case "EntryDate":
                query = (info.SortDirection == "ascending" ?
                    devicelogs.OrderBy(c => c.EntryDate) :
                    devicelogs.OrderByDescending(c => c.EntryDate));
                break;
            case "LogType":
               query = (info.SortDirection == "ascending" ?
                    devicelogs.OrderBy(c => c.DeviceLogType) :
                    devicelogs.OrderByDescending(c => c.DeviceLogType));
                break;
        }

        query = query.Skip(info.CurrentPageIndex * info.PageSize).Take(info.PageSize);
        ViewBag.PagingInfo = info;
        List<DeviceLog> model = query.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: As well as the answers also consider not passing PagingInfo with a viewbag but have your ViewModel class inherit a Paging class for better structure but that's optional.

Comment: I got past the issue however the paging and sorting is not working. Would this be an issue? I am not sure how to go about you suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view is strongly typed to `DeviceLogIndex`, but from your action method you are passing a `List<DeviceLog>` to the view. That is the reason you are getting the mismatch error.

To solve the issue, you should create an object of your `DeviceLogIndex` class and assign the DeviceLogs property value from your LINQ query result. and pass the `DeviceLogIndex` object to the view.

```
DeviceLogIndex vm = new DeviceLogIndex();

//your existing code goes here

var query = devicelogs.OrderBy(c => c.DeviceLogID).Take(info.PageSize);
vm.DeviceLogs=query.ToList();
return View(vm);
```

You can access `Model.DeviceLogs` in your view to access each Device item.

```
@model AQB_MON.ViewModels.DeviceLogIndex
@foreach(var item in Model.DeviceLogs)
{
  <p>@item.DeviceLogID</p>
}
```

Comment: Thank-you this got me past my error however now I just need to get the paging and sorting to work :)

Answer (score 2):

Your View is expecting a type `DeviceLogIndex`however you are passing it a type `List<DeviceLog>`

What you need to do instead is assign the `List<DeviceLog>` to the `DeviceLogIndex`

For Example:

```
DeviceLogIndex model = new DeviceLogIndex();
model.DeviceLogs = youDeviceLoglist;
return View(model);
```

Then in your View:

```
@foreach (var dl in Model.DeviceLogs)
{
    //Do something
}
```